# Can't display default text using html form and infobox.js

Tags: javascript, forms, infobox

Web designer novice here, so I hope these terms are correct and the question isn't too embarrassing. What I've got is an html form (in an html5 document) with 4 items (though there will be more):

1. Choose a page
2. Page 1
3. Page 2
4. Page 3

… and the text for each of those 3 pages, all hidden using CSS. When the page is first opened or refreshed "Choose a Page" is visible in the form menu box. When a page is chosen "infobox.js" (which I got somewhere on the net many years ago) makes the text for that page visible below the menu box. Works perfectly.

What I'd like instead: when the page is first opened "Choose a Page" is visible in the form menu box AND the text of Page 1 is already visible below it.

I'm assuming this is possible, but I've been just about tearing my hair out for a couple of days, and hoping the solution will be really easy for someone. Thanks in advance for any help!

HTML

```
<form>
<select id="someID_1" name="someID_1" onChange="selectForm1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option>Choose a Page</option>
<option value="1">Page 1</option>
<option value="2">Page 2</option>
<option value="3">Page 3</option>
</select>
</form>

<div id="allForms1">
<form class="hidden">Text of Page 1</form>
<form class="hidden">Text of Page 2</form>
<form class="hidden">Text of Page 3</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

INFOBOX.JS

```
function selectForm1(frm){
/* Select the div containing all the hidden forms */
  var hiddenForms1 = document.getElementById("allForms1");
/* Select every form within the above div and assign it to an array */
  theForm1 = hiddenForms1.getElementsByTagName("form");
/* Set the display for each of the above forms to NONE */
  for(x=0; x<theForm1.length; x++){
    theForm1[x].style.display = "none";
  }
/* If the form selected from the list exists, set its display to BLOCK */
  if (theForm1[frm-1]){
    theForm1[frm-1].style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I f-i-n-a-l-l-y- got it after yet another guess. This did the trick:

```
<body onload="selectForm1(1)">
```